# API error when trying to update composer and php

Tags: php, laravel, api

I had this errror in first instance:

Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">=
8.0.2". You are running 7.4.27. in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/proyectoCartas/vendor/composer/platform_check.php** on line

later I solved it by adding

```
    "platform-check": false
```

in composer.json config object
then i executed:
php artisan config:cache
php composer.phar dump-autoload

and still get this error, which I can't solve:

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet() must be an instance
of Illuminate\Container\mixed, instance of Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher returned in
/opt/lampp/htdocs/proyectoCartas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1417

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you update your PHP version?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't say which version of Laravel you're using, I assume it's the latest (9).
If so, you will have to update the PHP version, it has the minimum requirement of PHP version 8

[Server requirements Laravel 9](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#server-requirements)

Comment: when i check my php version: php -v
PHP 8.0.8 (cli) (built: Jul 12 2021 11:13:36) ( NTS )

Comment: Having the same issue after upgrading to PHP v8.0. When I run `php -v`, it shows the correct version. Help needed!